# mysql - Retrieve many results as the input parameters count

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the prices of a room in 3 different single dates. I have the dates and the room_id. 
The PRICES_CAL table is as follows:

```
id  room_id date_from   date_to   price 
1   1   2019-03-01  2019-04-01  100 
2   1   2019-04-02  2019-06-30  200 
3   1   2019-07-01  2019-08-31  400 
4   1   2019-09-01  2019-10-30  300
```

The problem is that, my query returns one single row when all three dates are in the same date_from - date_to interval.

For example, to search the prices for the dates 20190327, 20190328, 20190329, I use the query:

```
SELECT price 
FROM PRICES_CAL 
WHERE room_id = 1 AND ( 
      (date_from <= 20190327 AND date_to >= 20190327 ) 
   OR (date_from <= 20190328 AND date_to >= 20190328 ) 
   OR (date_from <= 20190329 AND date_to >= 20190329 ) 
) ORDER by date_from ASC;
```

and unfortunately I get only one result: That is

```
price
100
```

I would like to retrieve three lines of results, one for every date I provide.

I have already tried, among other 'no-hope' tries, to put `"SELECT RAND(), price ..."` in order to have a different row for each OR condition and hopefully get 3 results but I still retrieve one result. 
Also this:

```
SELECT @mydd, price 
FROM PRICES_CAL 
WHERE room_id = 1 AND ( date_from <= @mydd AND date_to >= @mydd  ) 
AND @mydd in (20190327, 20190328, 20190329) 
ORDER by date_from;
```

It doesn't work. It gives zero results. 
It could have been OK also with one result, but the main problem is that when I will get 2 results, I will not be able to know in which result my middle input_date belongs.

I want to avoid to execute 2 different statements for performance or to select date_from, date_to, price and make comparison with my dates in order to determine where my middle input date belongs.

The desired situation will be to resolve the problem with only one query.execute. 
I could sort it out with code inside the while statement when retrieving the result set and selecting everything from the table, but I would like also to learn how to that with query.
The desired solution will be to have three results

```
100
100
100
```

OR even better,

```
20190327 100
20190328 100
20190329 100
```

Any suggestion is welcome. thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you The Impaler ! I have tried to upvote and mark as green, your response but I have not the required reputation.. It is my solution though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get separate rows, you'll need to run one query per date and then `UNION` them. For example:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT '2019-03-27' as date_from, price 
  FROM PRICES_CAL 
  WHERE room_id = 1 AND date_from <= '2019-03-27' AND date_to >= '2019-03-27'
  UNION
  SELECT '2019-03-28' as date_from, price 
  FROM PRICES_CAL 
  WHERE room_id = 1 AND date_from <= '2019-03-28' AND date_to >= '2019-03-28'
  UNION
  SELECT '2019-03-29' as date_from, price 
  FROM PRICES_CAL 
  WHERE room_id = 1 AND date_from <= '2019-03-29' AND date_to >= '2019-03-29'
) x
order by date_from ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the requested dates in a separate (temporary) table and than join both tables:

```
SELECT   my_dates_table.requested_date,
         prices_cal.price
FROM     my_dates_table
JOIN     prices_cal
  ON     prices_cal.room_id = 1
 AND     my_dates_table.requested_date BETWEEN prices_cal.date_from AND prices_cal.date_to
ORDER BY my_dates_table.requested_date;
```

You should try a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in case the intervals are not contiguous (a gap between some `date_to` and the successive `date_from`).

This of course assumes that the various intervals in the `prices_cal` table are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a `LEFT JOIN`, as in:

```
select
  x.d, p.price
from (
  select '2019-03-27' as d
  union all select '2019-03-28'
  union all select '2019-03-29'
) x
left join prices_cal p on p.date_from <= x.d
                      and date_to >= x.d
                      and p.room_id = 1
```